# What would be the consequence if one does not drink a lot of water immediately after an MRI with contrast agent (intravenously injected)?

Tags: mri

Since the most commonly used compounds for contrast enhancement are gadolinium-based, which is toxic, would drinking very little water over the e.g. 5 hours after the MRI procedure result in some long-lasting effect (from disposition of gadolinium)?

Or can drinking a lot of water after that 5 hours can make up for drinking very little water over the 5 hours?

Comment: Did you do any research on this before asking the question? We require questions to demonstrate at least some minimal prior research here, but I don't see anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Toxicity of gadolinium-based contrast agents can generally be classified as acute (short term) and chronic (longer term) and include[¹](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30204075/):

- Acute allergic-like reactions
- Acute physiologic reaction
- Chronic kidney injury (called nephrogenic systemic fibrosis)

Additionally, there is evidence that a small amount of contrast agent is retained in various tissues of the body (including the brain), for years[¹](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30204075/), or potentially for life. The health effects of this gadolinium remain unknown.

Chronic kidney injury after gadolinium administration is overwhelmingly seen among individuals with pre-existing kidney disease[¹](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/30204075/).

There is some experimental evidence in animal models and retrospective review of patient data that suggests adequate intravenous hydration may decrease the risk of kidney injury[²](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/33450989/).

However, for individuals without kidney disease, I can find no evidence that hydration, either IV or oral, would have any clear effect on any adverse effects of gadolinium.